# Easiest way to check if Wine uses my discrete GPU (AMD)?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wine, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I'm using dedicated AMD GPU (HD 8570M) and it's installed correctly in my system.

```
  *-display                 
   description: Display controller
   product: Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:26 memory:b0000000-b7ffffff memory:b8000000-b803ffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b8040000-b805ffff
```

But upon playing game in Wine— it is barely playable, in Windows they **DO** ran smoothly, and I can confirm Windows actually uses the GPU. I suspected Wine uses my integrated Intel graphics instead.

How would I check that in Wine ? Is there any easy way to figure it out?

Comment: I am just trying to help you. This may help you. It says: "Problems with hybrid graphics are generally not Wine issues..." in forum https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=30494

Comment: How are you launching the game? Are you using `DRI_PRIME`?

Comment: @int_ua Yes, I'm using `DRI_PRIME`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to check for graphic card used, you can use the `WINDEBUG` environment variable with the `wgl` channel.

Example:

```
WINEDEBUG=+wgl wine game.exe &> wine.log
```

Wine will then output something similar to this

```
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo GL version             : 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8.
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo GL renderer            : Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2) .
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo GLX version            : 1.4.
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Server GLX version     : 1.4.
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Server GLX vendor:     : SGI.
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Client GLX version     : 1.4.
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Client GLX vendor:     : Mesa Project and SGI.
0036:trace:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo Direct rendering enabled: True
```

References:

- https://wiki.winehq.org/Debug_Channels
- https://wiki.winehq.org/3D_Driver_Issues